# How to catch a FetchFailure Exception in Flutter for image URLs that 404?

Tags: image, networking, dart, flutter

I have something like this:

```
try {
    final image = NetworkImageWithRetry(url,
        fetchStrategy: FetchStrategyBuilder(
            timeout: Duration(seconds: 2),
            transientHttpStatusCodePredicate: (code) {
              return code == null ||
                  FetchStrategyBuilder
                      .defaultTransientHttpStatusCodePredicate(code);
            }).build()
        );
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Image(
          image: image,
        ),
      );
  } catch FetchFailure {
    print('exception!');
    return Container();
  }
```

For a non-existent image, the image tries multiple times to load, and always throws:

```
EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY PACKAGE:FLUTTER_IMAGE
The following FetchFailure was thrown NetworkImageWithRetry failed to load
```

How do I catch this? I've tried `catch Exception`, `catch FetchFailure`, `catch (error)`.

I've also tried returning a widget based on the error code, but the `FetchStrategyBuilder` wants me to return a boolean.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the server returns 404? Give up and display an empty/null image?

Comment: Updated the question - I'd want to return the image with Padding if the image returns successfully. Otherwise, I'd want to return an empty Container (no extra Padding).

Comment: @RichardHeap no need to ask what he want to do next. the problem is simple. how to catch the error

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're not able to catch the FetchFailure error is because it's already catched inside [flutter_image](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image). This is pointed out in the error message you received: EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY PACKAGE:FLUTTER_IMAGE

Could you provide more details on why you're trying to catch the Exception? If the reason for this is you're trying to display a placeholder image in case the image failed to load, you can either use [FadeInImage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FadeInImage-class.html) or [CachedNetworkImage](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/cached-images).